# Will I be able to set a 2560x1440 resolution on a 27" screen?

Tags: video, drivers, nvidia, resolution

I just picked up one of those fancy Dell U2711 27" screens that has a maximum resolution of 2560x1440. While I await delivery, I need to upgrade my graphics card to drive this baby as my current one won't do the trick.

I am considering an EVGA with an nVidia GTS450 chip and dual DVI-I ports. It can go up to 2560x1600 in DVI-D mode with the corresponding dual link cable.

Should I expect any driver issues with this setup and the nVidia binary drivers? I have googled quite a bit and most people I found claiming problems with these resolutions are using notebooks (so either VGA or HDMI, that I don't think should work).

**Edit**: Is it possible alhough all the components are good up to 2560x1600, that they won't allow me to set 2560x1440? I've had this happen with some widescreen LCDs in the past where a video card would go up to a higher resolution, but the exact mode needed was not an option (resolutions such  1152x... come to mind).

**Conclusion**: Indeed, everything worked out of the box with the nVidia binary drivers in Meerkat. Just for future reference, I ended up using a GTX460 card with a dual-link DVI-D cable. Thanks!

Comment: It depends on the max. speed of the DAC in your video card and that of the ADC in your monitor what resolution is supported over a VGA cable (and of course the quality of the shielding in the VGA cable is relevant too).  CRT monitors that support at least 2560×1920 and maybe more over VGA do exist (and have existed for quite some time).

Comment: (Note that CRT monitors don't need an ADC, but your LCD screen does.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up to 2560x1600 is supported by both the DVI dual-link and nvidia driver.

It should "just work". Sounds like an awesome display.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting this [blog post](http://www.erikburrows.com/index.php?node=Dell+U2711+Display):

> I'm using the Displayport connector [...] and have no problems running at the full 2560x1440 resolution. Further, I had zero problems using the Nvidia driver that comes with Ubuntu. It detected the display, set the maximum resolution and refresh rate, and worked right out of the box.

I can only assume that it will work fine when using a dual link cable.

---

BTW, the [monitor's manual](http://supportapj.dell.com/support/edocs/MONITORS/U2711b/en/ug/operate.htm#Setting%20the%20Optimal%20Resolution) explicitly states that the HDMI resolution is limited to 1080p, so ignore all the threads where people complain about not getting 2560x1440 via HDMI. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm running dual display, 2048x1152 + 1280x1024 without trouble.

With a suitable graphics card and dual link hookup, I think you'll be fine.