# Ubuntu 12.04 network goes on and off

Tags: networking, network-manager

I have been using Ubuntu 12.04 for a long time. I update Ubuntu once in a month. The last time I updated networking issues started cropping up.

My internet connection disconnects, and after some long amount of time it reconnects.

I tried searching a lot and tried some solutions, but none of them works for me. The things that I tried are:

1. Editing `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` and adding `nameservers` (from google and open DNS) - I did this because I found DNS resolution itself fails, so I thought this might help.
2. Editing `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` turning off **dnsmasq**.
3. Ignoring **ipv6** as [suggested here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12761...ating-to-12-04).

...but nothing seems to correct it.

I have to disable-enable networking to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For wireless network, your connection may be not very stable. The interval of reconnecting may be set as a long time. You should check your wireless device, for me that is AR9485 using ath9k drivers. Try to create /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf, add  "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" into it and reboot.

WPA/WPA2 mixed mode has a very bad reputation here. Causes a lot of authentication problems. So whether it helps or not, keep the encryption to WPA2-only. This is one of the very few things I can recommend with confidence. see http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2080238

I suffered much from it recently. I think the best thing to do is get a better network connection. The connection quality talks much than your adjusting your own settings. Try to tolerate it.

Comment: Did you mean "much **more** than your adjusting your own settings"?

Comment: What do you mean by interval of reconnecting ?